# Batch convert with video passthrough, audio recode

Tags: batch, audio-conversion

How do I batch convert all files in a directory from mkv to mp4 where the video is passed through (not re-encoded) but the audio is converted (re-encoded)?

I thought it would be something like:

```
for file in *.mkv; do ffmpeg -i "$file" -acodec aac -vcodec copy "${file%.mkv}".mp4; done
```

but that isn't working.

Comment: It looks right, can you explain what isn't working?

Comment: I don't recall the exact message and I'm not at home right now, but it seemed to have something to do with the for command. The error message was along the lines of: no "(" after for.

Comment: I figured out the problem: I was using Powershell rather than cmd and for some reason they don't work the same. Now the command works fine. I also figured out how to remove the now unneeded file extension:
for %i in (*.mkv) do (ffmpeg -i "%i" -acodec aac -vcodec copy "%~ni".mp4)

Comment: Just so you know, that command won't work in `cmd` either - it is for the bash shell.